# How to alternate 2 onchange() functions in mvc razor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, onchange, cascadingdropdown

I have cascade drop down lists and I should to send form data to controller in every `onchange()` event. That is why I should to do 2 different operations on `onchange()` event of dropdownlist.

**1) This sends data to controller in every onchange() event of dropdowlists:(It is my first dropdownlist)**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, ViewBag.CategoryList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-",
 new { id = "CategoryDDL", onchange = "$('#MyForm').trigger('submit');" })
```

**2)This is for cascade dropdownlists:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#CategoryDDL").change(
        function () {
            loadLevelTwo(this);
        });
        loadLevelTwo($("#CategoryDDL"));
    });


function loadLevelTwo(selectList) {
       // my some code...
    }
</script>
```

In this case when I change  `CategoryDDL`  drop down list, 2 operations mix. It tries to do 2 operation together.

I want to alternate them. Firstly cascading operation works, then data submit operation works.
How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

Without `loadLevelTwo()` function, everything works well: when I change dropdown list, request goes to the controller to filter products. 
Then I added `loadLevelTwo()` for cascading dropdown list. Because I have 2 dropdownlist. I want when I change first dropdownlist, second dropdownlist updated automatically. My script does this. But, these events together works mixed. In the controller, I have actions for filtering an for cascading drop down:

```
public ActionResult FilterProducts(CriteriaModel model) {}
```

and

```
public ActionResult GetSubCategoryByCategoryId(int id) {}
```

These methods work in same time. One line works in any action, then gets into other action. then come backs first action, So, it is surrounded while actions return view.
I send form after `loadLevelTwo()` function, but it doesn't fix the issue:

```
    loadLevelTwo($("#CategoryDDL"));
    $('#MyForm').trigger('submit');
```

Comment: Are you trying to have the `change` event fire __both__ tasks, or do you want the _first_ change to call `loadLevelTwo` and a subsequent change to submit the form?

Comment: I want first change to call loadLevelTwo and then, send changed data to controller (submit the form)

Answer (score 1):

I'd get rid of the onchange on server side and do everything on clienside :

```
$(function () {
        $("#CategoryDDL").change(
        function () {
            loadLevelTwo(this);
        });
        loadLevelTwo($("#CategoryDDL"));
        $('#MyForm').trigger('submit');
    });
```

Comment: I agree with you, but this should be a comment. The code you've provided doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is still not clear what you are asking to do. If you simply want to submit the form and call `loadLevelTwo`, you can do that through a single binding in your script (and remove the `onchange` from razor):

```
$(function () {
    $("#CategoryDDL").on('change', function() {
        loadLevelTwo(this); // load the next level

        $("#MyForm").submit(); // submit the form
    });
});
```

This will complete both tasks in succession.